# Recursive type definition with mapped and conditional types

Tags: typescript, typeorm, mapped-types, conditional-types, keyof

I'm trying to come up with a way to have better type safety with TypeORM. The following are some example TypeORM entity definitions.

```js
import { BaseEntity, Entity, Column, ManyToMany, JoinTable, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
class Product extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  public name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  public description: string;

  @ManyToMany(_ => Category, category => category.products)
  @JoinTable()
  public categories: Category[];
}

@Entity()
class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  public name: string;

  @ManyToMany(_ => Product, product => product.categories)
  public products: Product[];

  @ManyToOne(_ => Supplier, supplier => supplier.categories, { nullable: false })
  public supplier: Supplier;
}

@Entity()
class Supplier extends BaseEntity {
  @Column('text')
  public name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true })
  public isActive: boolean;

  @OneToMany(_ => Category, category => category.supplier)
  public categories: Category[];
}
```

I'm trying to define a type which will be valid only for properties of an entity which are entities themselves. This is best explained with an example:

```js
type Relations<T extends BaseEntity> = {
  // An object whose:
  // - Keys are some (or all) of the keys in type T, whose type is something which extends BaseEntity.
  // - Values are another Relations object for that key.
}

// Some examples

// Type error: "color" is not a property of Product.
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  color: {}
}

// Type error: "name" property of Product is not something that extends "BaseEntity".
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  name: {}
}

// OK
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  categories: {}
}

// Type error: number is not assignable to Relations<Category>
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  categories: 42
}

// Type error: "description" is not a property of Category.
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  categories: {
    description: {}
  }
}

// Type error: "name" property of Category is not something that extends "BaseEntity".
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  categories: {
    name: {}
  }
}

// OK
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  categories: {
    supplier: {}
  }
}

// Type error: Date is not assignable to Relations<Supplier>
const a: Relations<Product> = {
  categories: {
    supplier: new Date()
  }
}

// etc.
```

I came up with the following so far but it doesn't work and probably not even close to the right answer:

```js
type Flatten<T> = T extends Array<infer I> ? I : T;

type ExcludeNonEntity<T> = T extends BaseEntity | Array<BaseEntity> ? Flatten<T> : never;

type Relations<T extends BaseEntity> = {
  [P in keyof T as ExcludeNonEntity<P>]: Relations<T[P]>;
};
```

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wXkEkW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please edit the example code to demonstrate the failing use case(s).

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, just saw this. Yes, it seems so, please do post an answer! Would also be very happy if you could explain what was wrong with my attempt and how could it have succeeded, if it ever could.

Comment: @jcalz Also just noticed the error in my entity code (`supplier => supplier.categories`) and your comment about it. Apparently, supplier entity has a relation to category like `public categories: Category[];` as well but I forgot to include it in my code sample. Updated the code sample to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be something like this:

```
type DrillDownToEntity<T> = T extends BaseEntity ?
    T : T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? DrillDownToEntity<U> : never;

type Relations<T extends BaseEntity> =
    { [K in keyof T]?: Relations<DrillDownToEntity<T[K]>> }
```

The `DrillDownToEntity<T>` is something like your `Flatten<T>` type mixed with `ExcludeNonEntity<T>`, except that it acts recursively.  It extracting all array element types for any arbitrary amount of nesting, keeping only those types assignable to `BaseEntity`.  Observe:

```
type DrillTest = DrillDownToEntity<Category | string | Product[] | Supplier[][][][][]>
// type DrillTest = Category | Product | Supplier
```

I don't know if you are ever going to have arrays-of-arrays; if you aren't, you can make this non-recursive.  Importantly, though, any type not ultimately assignable to `BaseEntity` is discarded.

Then `Relations<T>` is a type with all optional properties, whose keys are from `T`, and whose values are `Relations<DrillDownToEntity<>>` of the properties of `T`.  Generally speaking, most properties will be of type `never`, since most properties are not themselves assignable to `BaseEntity`.  Observe:

```
type RelationsProduct = Relations<Product>;
/* type RelationsProduct = {
    name?: undefined;
    description?: undefined;
    categories?: Relations<Category> | undefined;
    hasId?: undefined;
    save?: undefined;
    remove?: undefined;
    softRemove?: undefined;
    recover?: undefined;
    reload?: undefined;
} */
```

Note that an optional property of type `never` and one of type `undefined` are the same, at least without [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) enabled. This has the effect of preventing you from assigning any property of these types at all unless they are `undefined`.  I find this is probably better than merely *omitting* those properties; a value of type `{categories?: Relations<Category>}` might or might not have a `string`-valued `name` property, according to [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), while one of the form `{categories?: Relations<Category>, name?: never}` will definitely not have a defined `name` property at all.

You can verify that your example code works as desired with this definition of `Relations`.

---

The following code:

```
type Relations<T extends BaseEntity> = {
    [P in keyof T as ExcludeNonEntity<P>]: Relations<T[P]>;
};
```

does not work for several reasons, the most immediate of which is that you are using [key remapping syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to presumably suppress non-`BaseEntity`-assignable properties, but you are writing `ExcludeNonEntity<P>` where `P` is a *key* type.  And no *keys* are going to be `BaseEntity`, so that is very likely to end up excluding all keys, even if you could get it to work.  If you want to suppress keys, then you would need to check `T[P]` and not `P`, and then omit or include `P` based on that.  There are other minor issues (e.g., properties are not optional) but the big one is treating keys as if they were values.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=75&pln=42&pc=76#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQIYGcCmBRAdjYGATwBo48DiyBhCAGwFcRcyBZVXIgFQnc7IBSEYLi6oARnUxsO3CAHlc0uIsw8+ROAF84AMygQQcAOTEwmaCGMBuAFC2AAhUJEAFAEpbAYzoZ0cAAUDABMGL3hMAA8YTFxg-zQsZ2JEWzh0uAdaRmZXJDNMAC4TGOjjbU8MuDAGSWAvOFxUEEwAQmL0GCgRAHM7NIys+iZcPLgC4tMomHKtSoyauobgzHQvbrACCFx2uE7u3D77KocNdVlXAH04AF4APjhqVBie6FI4L2fMV6hNe4+vj8iAA6MAhMIwdDzdIOIQiMSSTAeAbpRZ0eoAl7QYCrXZPLG-ADaAF07Fp7E58C5kT4-I9AW84NNYvEUBgcFSUggUZlsiMxhMStNZtDqrV0Q0mi1dvtev0TmdeBdrv8ghBQuEyGD1RDbg9tRqYMDPgScVCeWiMQaIehdmrDST5YNFaornq4ABlBhgMDozBQMjob2+nFQd1Bn1+qDGhndVZkJC4Bh0XyI4q6VB0LAVOAAelzcAAPABaYtwADuAAtnsZ-DBK8B0BbxRiIyH-bsvZHQ2SKck3J5aeh-F322HmXEEuz+6kTnzclMyqLLZLmm0Ol05cdBvPRvkiOZJuIIPRMBxjGQVhnkzBil0GJgKs2lnBGwBBcLAABu67gx9PHBOjCqjnJwbr-Pi3xvGQJpQb87qwUCwJtlGy4tg0iHYrixSQUCjq2OSthSqsYCoF4j7yN0PSzhkBRwAAYr4MAxLghZcA8NxwFwTLRCy-hvlAUCoEQhYiLo-pwAAkg8AD8UlwMUXB2FUdHYJEPgMCsABy2z9mxHFcTxLGsokHKUJoAA+cACUJImmf2skMUxLH6QpjSYD+UBAeMB6PgASpgTHANs6BsUZfFskknJEAZ3JVFU+ZwISASvrgcAANaYEQEC6IZGDkOpjDabp0WFgEdzEsUAVBSFbHJcSdzKRkWi9vYdEACLdCm7UQOWogQHp7G3IZE4mdO0VwDJPLcYp4WTnAAWoME2x0EQNnCaJuDiWGACqjmdcA3W9f1el7W5Sief0HVdXQXCrPAnEHUdfU8HpuGMlZsqHHAVn2hCJI-Z6wZRiSoPEmDdy2Il12Hbd93De98G-eC4SA6OUZtb5C2Bc8wW4KF3GjVOUXmRxPJIISADSqUZVlOVccSMlVTjWz44WT10D1L0DaVXBUw1DyEXR1W4yFf2o5xIus6F4swI1UMAFQ+eY2M1fjsvDXFGTEUzcAMHEmC6CImDBE16QrGsGys7r+tXsbps8phcboLrUt46FiMxYDtuG-bZtwNW6CScENsG0bSgO1U6CoD+od2xH-tQJgIAQLHxQ++HJv++gOUwAFKdp3rYd+zySdeKn-px77Cel4FEBLVXmcOzoCu5vYiUeoYj5RM0vqrO3BZcFj-oGFAxQAETl3Q0Dj6+-i4BA8CoNUBjmLAmj07LwLeCFS-M2rMso3LmuO-Q0DFAg5KEYlQ8qyP59wOPxGz9qa8pJvR9z40i97F39a9OMasEReLzXHvZaK49t7l3xvAcQ+9RZs1lrFHkxEL5XwHioSmO8YEfHgdLMqR9kFVCdmaNBBEMG327oJB+SYQDiAko2b+S9hzAB6E0RE4wICqwQR7WMMVsGdDgMEPB7sCE6nCEQjIJDVjFAACwACZyFQ0HsPahY9H4W3WMATYeNZ6MIXkvFeEA34b1yp7KBu8mQiNqkgk+xDYykJovFIRqwtE6O2GQqo6DlFcVUaPCez8jEmLgPTT2X8DG-xaP-b69ZnhzVZGA8a5lIECPgLoaxiDCF2KkQ4mRTj4qoMQOSLxSifHyCwdAwRPQMmH3EcfTiWt0jSPQBfHkUdgahk8c1JRN8-EP3al8cJP8-CsPYVITh3D8Ho1DJDSp8BKw1LEYaSRTTcktPye07s-pihKHLHAAZMRkQlOvgWTAMAvDAiAA)

Comment: BTW why `ReadonlyArray` instead of just `Array`? More importantly, how does this code work even though all arrays in the sample entities are not (at least don't seem to be) `ReadonlyArray`s? All of them seem like regular arrays, since they neither have a `readonly` modifier, nor they are declared using `ReadonlyArray`. If you have a previous answer about that, you can just link that as well.

Comment: `ReadonlyArray` is a TS-specific type which is a supertype of `Array`.  Every `Array` is a `ReadonlyArray` but not every `ReadonlyArray` is an `Array`.  Thus `ReadonlyArray` is more accepting than `Array`.

Comment: Do you have any answers, blog posts, etc. about `ReadonlyArray` being a supertype of `Array`? I can't understand why that's the case. I think, "whenever I need an `Array`, I can accept a `ReadonlyArray` but whenever I need a `ReadonlyArray`, I cannot accept an `Array`, since it might not be read-only". So, this makes me think that actually `Array` should be a supertype of `ReadonlyArray`.

Comment: The [doc for `ReadonlyArray`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) says that you can assign arrays to readonlyarrays but not vice versa.  You should think "A `ReadonlyArray` is not *known* to have the methods that mutate the contents, but it *may*". Instead of `ReadonlyArray` it's more like `NotKnownToBeWritableArray`... maybe instead of `Array/ReadonlyArray` it should be `ReadWriteArray/ReadArray` (but they can't really rename `Array`).  It's a little more nuanced than that but that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413727/3395831):

```js
type Relations<T extends BaseEntity> = {
    [K in keyof T as DrillDownToEntity<T[K]> extends never ? never : K]?: Relations<DrillDownToEntity<T[K]>>
}
```

This way, the following will result in a type error as well, whereas it does not result in an error with [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413727/3395831):

```js
const b: Relations<Product> = {
    name: undefined
}
```

This answer is inspired by the following section in [Anders Hejlsberg's PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336#issue-689531932):

> When the type specified in an `as` clause resolves to `never`, no property is generated for that key. Thus, an `as` clause can be used as a filter:
>
> ```js
> type Methods<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Function ? P : never]: T[P] };
> type T60 = Methods<{ foo(): number, bar: boolean }>;  // { foo(): number }
> ```